# CSS Help: One div refuses to behave like the other div

Tags: html, css

I am just starting to learn CSS and am having a helluva time figuring what I'm doing wrong here.

I've got two divs, a banner with a logo in it and the main content body. I want the banner div to stick to the top -- not fixed, just zero pixels from the top. The content div will do this if I remove the banner HTML and change `top: 200px` to 0px in `#content-block`, but the banner div refuses to hug the top edge.

What am I failing to grasp here?

http://jsfiddle.net/j58agvq1/2/

CSS:

```
#banner-block {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 80%;
height: 200px;
margin-left: 10%;
text-align: right;
z-index: 1;
background: rgb(240, 73, 37);
}

#content-block {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 10%;
z-index: 1;
background: rgb(25, 9, 0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Banner Div -->
<p id="banner-block">
    <img src="./images/logo.png" height="200"/>
</p>

<!-- Content Div -->
<div id="content-block">
    <p>This is some content text to test the content block.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the default margin on your `#banner-block` element:

```
margin-top:0;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j58agvq1/3/)**

Comment: Thanks. But can you help me understand the issue more? I don't have `margin-top: 0` in `#content-block`, so why are they behaving differently?

Comment: Sure, the reason why you didn't need to do that for your content-block div is because you position that absolutely and set the top to zero, which removes it from the flow of the document and sticks it at the top of the document, ignoring any margins or padding.

Comment: I thought I did the same thing with `#banner-block`. I even copy/pasted the code right from `#content-block` to make sure it was identical, then made my edits. There's definitely something I'm missing.

Comment: The paragraph and body elements have a default margin but divs don't.

Comment: Ah-ha! I had mistakenly used a `<p>` for `#banner-block`, so it technically wasn't even a div. That was my *real* problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As answer is already given by j08691 first above but i would like to give you a tip in such situation. In such situation just do open up your developer panel in browser usually called Web Inspector (in case you don't know you can find it by right click on document). Then select that element which makes you headache and then in right you will see option like "metrics" is Safari and "Box Model" in firefox and for other browsers you can make some search and that option should be in right side after selecting an node(element) in any browser. Here you can check how padding,borders,margin are given to your box(div in your case here). If you check your page you will find there is margin being in top so you can do `margin-top:0px` in CSS that's all. Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I definitely need to get better at using the browser's dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```css
#banner-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 10%;
     margin-top:0;
 text-align: right;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgb(240, 73, 37);
}
#content-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgb(25, 9, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- Banner Div -->
    <p id="banner-block">
        <img src="./images/logo.png" height="200"/>
    </p>
    <!-- Content Div -->
    <div id="content-block">
        <p>This is some content text to test the content block.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great.Please mark it as answer & voteup :) @PaulGarrett